# Encoding json files to create flotcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, json, charts

I need to create some charts for a little project and i'm trying to learn how to use the charts from http://www.flotcharts.org/.
My problem is that i need to insert data dinamically (everytime the page is refreshed - so AJAX is not necessary -) from mysql queries and i don't understand how to build the needed json file.
Here is an example of the json requested:

```js
//Flot Pie Chart
$(function() {
    var data = [{
        label: "Series 0",
        data: 1
    }, {
        label: "Series 1",
        data: 3
    }, {
        label: "Series 2",
        data: 9
    }, {
        label: "Series 3",
        data: 20
    }];

    var plotObj = $.plot($("#flot-pie-chart"), data, {
        series: {
            pie: {
                show: true
            }
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true
        },
        tooltip: true,
        tooltipOpts: {
            content: "%p.0%, %s", // show percentages, rounding to 2 decimal places
            shifts: {
                x: 20,
                y: 0
            },
            defaultTheme: false
        }
    });

});
```

Someone can give me help or some good advice? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to output json in the backend.
Example: if you are using php, you can use the json_encode() function to encode your data (from the MySQL query) and set it to a javascript variable.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// pass PHP variable declared above to JavaScript variable
var data = <?php echo json_encode($myqueryresult) ?>;
</script>
```

From: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/array.php